# Can ElasticSearch be used as a persistent store for Apache Ignite?

Tags: elasticsearch, ignite, elasticsearch-2.0

I want to know if there's a way to configure the datasource for Ignite as Elastic Search. I was browsing the web. But I did not find a solution.

I want to implement this integration for a Java application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your idea correctly there's a way to do it. As far as I can [see](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/sql-jdbc.html) Elasticsearch supports `SQL` table-like data access and it's available through `jdbc` connection. From the Ignite's side we have [3rd party persistance](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/3rd-party-store), it uses `jdbc` to connect to an underlying store system. To be honest I haven't tested it but I suppose it should work.

Also I need mention that you can use [GridGain WebConsole](https://console.gridgain.com/) to generate simple Ignite project from existing `jdbc` connection. This functionality could be found on Configuration tab -> Create Cluster Configuration.

Comment: You can also write a custom Cache Store. However, I'm not sure if ElasticSearch is a good fit as a random write access database.

Comment: @Vladimir I will try it out.

Comment: @alamar "However, I'm not sure if ElasticSearch is a good fit as a random write access database." - Can you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: Lucene-based search index usually have to keep updates in a separate index and merge it with their main index from time to time. I'm not sure how this will perform when updates are coming continuously from multiple directions. Maybe it's a solved problem, but I'm not aware.

Comment: @alamar any LSM backed databased also does the same! Examples include Cassandra, RocksDB, etc...